# org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'eclipselink.tenant-id' of bean class []

Tags: spring, eclipselink

I am facing the below error whenever i try to save any data to the Emloyee entity.

org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'eclipselink.tenant-id' of bean class [com.sample.model.Employee]: Could not find field for property during fallback access!

This error occurs when i make the Tenant Discriminator Column a primary key.

```
@Entity
@Multitenant
@TenantDiscriminatorColumn(name = "TENANT_ID", length = 36, contextProperty = PersistenceUnitProperties.MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT, primaryKey = true)
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee implements Serializable { 
@Id
private String Id;

private String name;

......
......
}
```

I have implemented the Spring data JPA repository and it handles the multi tenant scenarios. As i said everything works fine when the Tenant Discriminator Column is a non primary key, but it fails to save data once i make the Tenant Discriminator Column as a primary key.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Regards,
Ranjan

Comment: Can u show where u are setting tenantId to the context for ORM

Comment: @AshishRatan I followed the blog http://codecrafters.blogspot.in/2013/03/multi-tenant-cloud-applications-with.html to set up the multitenant with Spring data jpa and eclipse link. tenant id is set after the transaction begins and done thorugh the MultiTenantJpaRepositoryFactoryBean which extends the JpaRepositoryFactoryBean. I am very new to JAVA developments, so please excuse me in case i am not using the right technical terms.

Comment: Are u sure if u can make tenant_id as your primary key ? i will never ever suggest it to make it primary key.

Comment: We have a requirement where i have a composite key for example id1 and id2. And for different tenants the combinations of id1 and id2 could be same. to avoid unique constraint error we want to make tenant id also a primary key.

Comment: My confusion is why spring checks for the eclipselink.tenant-id as this is already filled automatically by the spring data custom repository. And this issue is when i make the tenant id as primary but all works if its just a field

Comment: What is the code you are using to get the result ?

Comment: Instead of using the PersistenceUnitProperties.MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT, i used "tenantId" and defined a read only column "tenantId" with its getter.

Answer (score 0):

found an alternative to make it work.

1. Defined my own ContextPropertyName, example: tenantId for the TenantDiscriminatorColumn.
2. Filled this property in the Spring data custom repository.